# React native maps move to coordinate change

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

In my app, I have google map. It is implemented as given below.

```
<MapView style={[styles.mapStyle, { flex: 1, width: this.state.mapWidth }]}
                            initialRegion={{
                                latitude: this.state.latitude,
                                longitude: this.state.longitude,
                                latitudeDelta: 0.1,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.1,
                            }}
                            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                            onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}
                            showsUserLocation={true}
                            followsUserLocation={true}
                            showsMyLocationButton={true}
                            showsCompass={true}
                            showsTraffic={true}
                            toolbarEnabled={true}
                            onMapReady={() => this.setState({ width: width - 1 })}
                        >
                            <Marker draggable
                                coordinate={{
                                    latitude: this.state.latitude,
                                    longitude: this.state.longitude,
                                }}
                                onDragEnd={(e) => this.setState({ x: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}
                            />
                            <Circle
                                center={{
                                    latitude: this.state.latitude,
                                    longitude: this.state.longitude,
                                }}
                                radius={this.state.radius}
                                fillColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,0.5)'
                                strokeColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,1)'
                            />
   </MapView>
```

When I click on a button I change the state value of region of the the map.

```
changeRegion(){
    this.setState({ latitude: 6.86, longitude: 6.86 });
}
```

This successfully changes the position of the marker of the map.

My problem is, map doesn't move to selected position. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a ref for your Map

```
const mapRef = React.createRef();
```

Pass the ref to your Map

```
<Map
  ref={mapRef}
  // Rest of your props
/>
```

Modify your function

```
changeRegion(){
  const latitude = 6.86;
  const longitude = 6.86;
  this.setState({ latitude, longitude });
  mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
    latitude,
    longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1
  })
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this animates my view to the equator, and my marker moves to my location! Wierd.

Comment: This one worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171389/1928149

Answer (score 2):

based on @Dan's answer, modify a little bit if that answer does not work for you:

```
changeRegion(){
  const targetLatitude = 6.86;
  const targetLongitude = 6.86;
  this.setState({ latitude, longitude });

  mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
    latitude: targetLatitude,
    longitude: targetLongitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.1,
    longitudeDelta: 0.1
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use useRef for functional component

```
 const mapRef = useRef(null);
 const [region, setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: LATITUDE,
    longitude: LONGITUDE,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  });

    const onRegionCHange=()=>{
      mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion({
            latitude: your desired latitude,
            longitude: your desired longitude,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
              longitudeDelta:LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            });
    }
        <MapView
                ref={mapRef}
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChange}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={region}
                zoomEnabled={true}
                maxZoomLevel={zoom + 1}
                minZoomLevel={zoom + 0.5}
                scrollEnabled={true}
                showsScale={true}
                zoomControlEnabled={true}
                zoomTapEnabled={true}
                mapType={'satellite'}
                rotateEnabled={true}
        
                loadingEnabled={true}
                showsCompass={true}>
        </MapView>
```