# react-native-maps animateToRegion not wirking

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

**i am using react-native-maps in my expo application ,i'm trying to animate to different regions but when the button is clicked nothing happens**

```
    const mapRef = useRef(null);
```

```
 const moveTo = () => {
        if (mapRef.current) {
            mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
                latitude: 34.67264651170966,
                longitude: 3.2496815480574,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }, 20);
        }
    }
```

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                ref={mapRef}
                showsUserLocation
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 36.74041655479224,
                    longitude: 3.344924892773676,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
                onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => setcurrentLocalisation(region)}
            >
            </MapView>
            <Button style={styles.btn} onPress={moveTo}>Move</Button>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using this method instead :

```
mapRef?.current?.animateCamera({
 center: {
   latitude: 34.67264651170966,
   longitude: 3.344924892773676
 }
})
```